# Write a program that prints the following output

Tags: loops, processing

Input:

```
 1 + 1 = 2 1 + 2 = 3...1 + 10 = 11 2 + 1 = 3 2 + 2 = 4 ... 3 + 1 = 4 ... 10 + 10 = 20
```

Right now I have:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j<=10; j++) {
     println(i + j);
  }
}
```

It prints the answer to the problems ; 2 3 4. It needs to print the entire problem. How do I do that? (In processing)

Comment: What iwill be your expected  input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation technique for this

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    console.log(i+' + '+j+' =  %d', i+j);
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is for Processing, not Javascript

Comment: @c2huc2hu this can be done in processing also by a little syntax changes like println and int the answer is to show the path which is concatination